# profiling tools for mvc app with very high cpu

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, profiling, windows-server-2008

I am currently running an asp.net mvc application and under high load I am seeing the site maxing out at 100%. This should not be the case and I believe there may be an issue with the application that is degrading performance. This application communicates directly to wcf services layer which communicates to a sql server database. Neither the wcf layer or database layer have any performance issues as the 100% CPU can be directly apportioned to the MVC app.

Therefore I am looking at profiling where the issue may be in the MVC app - preferably without changing any code. The server is a windows server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5.

What tools are available to be to assist with this? For starters I have been looking setting some performance counters.

Comment: http://miniprofiler.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it seems like a daunting task getting started, but start slow and try to develop a hypothesis for why your application is experiencing such degraded performance. A good place to start is with basic perfmon counters and [debugdiag](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26798), as per this article:

[Troubleshooting High CPU in an IIS 7.x Application Pool](http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/performance-issues/troubleshooting-high-cpu-in-an-iis-7x-application-pool)

There are tons of SO posts on this topic, so definitely do your research. A good profiler can definitely help here, for ASP.NET MVC apps I'd recommend [Red Gate ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/), because it can show you where and how long calls to DBs and other downstream systems are taking.

Answer (score 0):

If a program takes 100% of the core it's running on, that means its ratio of CPU time to I/O (or sleep) time is very high.
If that is normal, then you could reduce the CPU time by an order of magnitude and it could still be showing almost 100% CPU, even though it is getting ten times as much work done.
All that means is there are better performance diagnostics than CPU percent.

A good one is: how many transactions per second or minute does it handle? If that number goes down, you know you have a problem to solve.

The method I use is to get [*stackshot samples*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771) during the slowness and examine them. If there's something suspect going on 50% of the time, for example, then it will be seen, in precise detail, on roughly 50% of the samples.
You don't need a lot of samples to see this, but you do need to examine each one.
Measurements are not very good at telling you what's going on.